# I can not see PrimeFaces theme with spring security

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I hope to explain well, I'm working on a project using JSF2.2-Spring-Maven and I have integrated spring-security, "which works well".
When I try to incorporate a theme PrimeFaces, the login page repeats 2 times

and after redirected to the welcome page

when i comment this line in springSecurityContext.xml

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />
```

all works fine, but i can not see the Primefaces theme

i dont know where is the error or is a very silly mistake
Please help me
thank you very much
regards

Comment: This blog article [http://marco-ng.blogspot.de/2014/02/primefaces-jsf2-spring-security-spring.html] explain it in detail, you may take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Does primeFaces works good before using spring security ?

Show us your web.xml?

I think that this line that you include to spring configuration isn't necessary:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />
```

Comment: The problem is solved, It was too silly, the web.xml and the springSecurityContext.xml are well. Only i added primefaces components in the redirect page and worked well. Thanks